# LS-SVM: maximum value for parameter of regularization based on number of samples

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am using ls_svm for a data set of 24*468. my variable selection and SVM parameter tuning are based on leave one out CV. increasing upper bound of regularization parameter results in better Q2 (leave one out coefficient) but improvement of test set results is not as well. is there a relationship between number of samples (24) and maximum regularization parameter?

Comment: interesting question, but off-topic here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to clarify two things, hyperparameter `C` is actually the inverse of the regularization. Bigger the `C` - smaller the regularization. From your question I suppose that you are interested in upper bound of `C`, which is actually lower bound of regularization. I am pretty sure that you cannot have such value based solely on the number of points. Why? Because SVM is not affine transformations invariant, so if I simply scale your whole dataset 2 times, you will need bigger `C` to get the very same results as before scaling. In other words - actual scale/position of your points is crucial. Unfortunately even for correctly scaled data - as far as I know - there is no upper bound of `C`, there is however the lower one - you can compute the smallest `C` for which SVM leads to non-trivial model. However on the opposite end - it seems as a more complex optimization problem than SVM itself.

Comment: actually i am interested in upper bound of C. as you said, i couldn't find any criterion to set upper bound. since high C stresses good fitting of all the training data points, i get great statistics by increasing C. however considering test statistics, overfitting is obvious. i want to find a way to increase C as large as it can be without causing overfitting.

Comment: This is what the validation set is for (quick tip: LOO rarely gives proper estimate, it is only good for theoretical analysis, not actual fitting of hyperparamteres). There is no way to give you a bound on "when do I overfit" - this is simply impossible. The only possible bound would be "after increasing from this point, your classifier will not change at all", but I am nearly 100% sure that one can prove that no such bound exists (at least in general, not in some degenerated, simple cases)

Comment: I will use  5 or 10 fold cross validation instead of LOO. thank you very much.